# flask application is very slow

Tags: python, flask

I am currently developing an app that is served with a flask web server.

The back end python code has become extremely huge (to the tune of 1000 lines of code to give readers a perspective) with a lot of dependencies.

As a result, even simple api calls such as this:

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def hello():
    return "Sample"
```

results in the request taking close to 900 ms to serve.

Would anyone be able to give me tips on improving the latency?  Would blueprinting help in this scenario?

The dependencies we have are all critical (we could perhaps remove one or two of them, but thats about it)...

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks,
Galeej

Comment: You can only optimize what you measure; so before you do anything, put some instrumentation to find out _where_ is the problem exactly.

Comment: Are you using flask development server, or are you deploying that with WSGI?

Comment: To know why things are slow you have to measure. Where is the time spent? I doubt it's in the function you showed. Flask doesn't care what other code there is (well maybe when deployed via CGI) so lines of code doesn't really mean anything (even then 1000 lines of code isn't really "extremely huge"). Do you have any WSGI middleware? Any proxies before the request hits python? The time must be spent somewhere.

Comment: @FilipMalczak we're deploying it using Gevent

Comment: @syntonym is there someway i can check where the time is spent when I give out a request?  I tried apache benchmark and I couldn't extract anything meaningful.

Comment: @syntonym we do not have any proxies.  We do however have a few before_request operations (I do not think it should take that much time though).  Middleware - Gevent

Comment: Use a python profiler, personally i go with [line_profiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) but there should be other options around. You could also try to log the time at the beginning of each (interesting aka the before_request) function and the end of each function.

Answer (score 2):

**Flask is a microframework for Python. It is not a web server.**

A lot of reasons would cause a slow response. 
 But I don't think dependencies or blueprinting is the problem. 
If you can provide how you deploy your app that would be helpful.

I think the most critical and simple thing is to log timestamp of each main process, then find which part cost a lot.

Comment: We've deployed it using Gevent.  Is there a way to enable logging in gevent?

Comment: I am not familar with gevent. But you can start a flask daemon without gevent, then access this method and check the response time cost.